# Using Almofireimage to set image in a Custom Tableview Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, alamofireimage

I'm using Alamofireimage to set an image based on a remote url on a `UIImageView` in my Custom `UITableViewCell` however the results are (1) the images aren't set until you scroll and (2) even though I'm using StackViews for my autolayout the sizes of the images displayed in the app vary wildly.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage

class AppsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let session = URLSession.shared

    var rekos: [Reko]? {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        RekoManager().downloadAndConvertRekos(rekoType: .apps) { (result) in
            print("Reko Count = \(result.count)")
            self.rekos = result
        }


    }



    // MARK: - Table view data source


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

          guard let count = rekos?.count else {return 0}
        return count 
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AppCell", for: indexPath) as! AppsTableViewCell

        if let reko = rekos?[indexPath.row] {



            cell.titleLabel.text = reko.title
            cell.descriptionLabel.text = reko.description
            if let imageUrlString = reko.imageUrlString {

                if let imageURL = URL(string: imageUrlString) {

                    //TODO IMPLEMENT SPINNER OVER IMAGE
                    cell.appImageView.af_setImage(withURL: imageURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"), filter: nil, progress: nil, progressQueue: DispatchQueue.main, imageTransition: .noTransition, runImageTransitionIfCached: false, completion: { (result) in
                        cell.setNeedsLayout()
                        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                    })

                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: `RekoManager().downloadAndConvertRekos` runs in async task so when your tableview displayed, `RekoManager().downloadAndConvertRekos` has not completed and it has no image for displaying. After             `self.rekos = result`, reload yourTableView for displaying image.

Comment: I do don't I? Rekos is a computed property that reloads the tableview when it's set?